# Selected field is not included in GROUP BY clause, so how does this Access query run successfully?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I found this query in an MS Access database that was built by someone else:

```
SELECT
      tblWorkOrder.WorkOrderNum
    , tblWorkOrder.SprayTypes
    , tblWorkOrder.Description
    , tblWorkOrderMaterials.ChemicalName
    , tblWorkOrderMaterials.RatePerAcre
    , tblMaterials.ApplicationUnit
    , tblMaterials.DryOrLiquid
    , tblWorkOrderMaterials.ID
FROM (tblMaterials
INNER JOIN tblMaterialsDetails ON tblMaterials.ChemicalName = tblMaterialsDetails.ChemicalName)
INNER JOIN (tblWorkOrder
INNER JOIN tblWorkOrderMaterials ON tblWorkOrder.WorkOrderNum = tblWorkOrderMaterials.WorkOrderNum) ON tblMaterials.ChemicalName = tblWorkOrderMaterials.ChemicalName
WHERE (((tblMaterialsDetails.CropType) = "Apples"
OR (tblMaterialsDetails.CropType) = "All"))
GROUP BY
      tblWorkOrder.WorkOrderNum
    , tblWorkOrder.Description
    , tblWorkOrderMaterials.ChemicalName
    , tblWorkOrderMaterials.RatePerAcre
    , tblMaterials.ApplicationUnit
    , tblMaterials.DryOrLiquid
    , tblWorkOrderMaterials.ID;
```

The query runs fine in Access, which is the problem. How does this query run when field "tblWorkOrder.SprayTypes" is included in the `SELECT` list but not in the `GROUP BY` clause? It should cause an error based on the field not being included in the aggregate function, right? When I migrated the back end to MySQL, it broke like I would expect it to so I want to make sure I wasn't missing something in the Access back end version.

Here is the relationship between tblWorkOrder and tblSprayTypes:

[image]

Comment: Not that I would expect this from Access, but it is possible to leave out columns in a group by clause if those columns are "functionally dependent" on some other column which is specified in that clause. Perhaps Access has some meta data about `tblWorkOrder.SprayTypes` that MySQL does not. Is that column an enumeration?

Comment: Looks like tblWorkOrder.SprayTypes is a text field but in the Access database it looks up its value from a separate SprayTypes table.

Comment: Then that is your answer I believe, if it "just a text column" then it would need to be in the group by clause, if the "functional dependence" is determined by other columns in the group by then it can be ommitted. This is why, in practical terms, it is always easier to include all non-aggregating columns in the group by clause.

Comment: Is the data type of *SprayTables* a [calculated field](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-14a60733-2580-48c2-b402-6de54fafbde3)?

Comment: @Parfait it is not calculated.

Comment: Screenshot the table relationships. Is *SprayTables* referentially linked to another table's field?

Comment: It is referentially linked to another table's field. See the edited post for a screen shot. And in the migrated database with MySQL server back end, this relationship does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

It runs successfully because there is nothing in the select clause that necessitates a group by clause.  There is no min, max, sum, count, or avg.

The point of the group by clause is not clear, but that wasn't your question.